# Master-detail in XAML with - managing ListView selection through binding/commands whilst allowing cancellation

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism, mvvm-light

I'm attempting to build a WPF application for demonstration that follows the best possible MVVM practices, and I've found quickly that I'm not sure what the best practices are! :)

I have a specific issue right now.

As some background (in case it shows in my snippets), I'm using MVVMLight (for its PCL portability), NInject as a container and Prism for its region support.

### View

[snippet]

```
        <!-- bind the selection of a new item to the view model -->
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectTypeCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <!-- visual template of the list items -->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock>Name: <Run Text="{Binding Name}"></Run></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <!-- detail view -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
            <Label>ID</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedType.Id, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
            <Label>Name</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedType.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

### ViewModel

[snippet]

```
public class ClientTypesViewModel : BaseUpdateableViewModel
{
    private ThingType selectedtype = null;

    public ThingType SelectedType
    {
        get { return selectedtype; }
        protected set { Set(() => SelectedType, ref selectedtype, value); }
    }

    private RelayCommand<ThingType> selecttypecommand;

    public RelayCommand<ThingType> SelectTypeCommand
    {
        get { return selecttypecommand ?? (selecttypecommand = new RelayCommand<ThingType>(ExecuteSelectTypeCommand)); }
    }

    private async void ExecuteSelectTypeCommand(ThingType newtype)
    {
        // Save the type if required - goes away to a service (HttpClient...)
        if (!await SaveSelectedType())
        {
            // Cancel navigation?
            return;
        }

        // Update the selected type
        this.SelectedType = newtype;
    }

    private async Task<bool> SaveSelectedType()
    {
            if (selectedtype == null) return true;
            if (!selectedtype.IsDirty) return true;

            bool? result = await navigationservice.AskConfirmation("Do you want to save this client type?", "Yes", "No", "Cancel");

            if (result == null) 
                return false; // cancel

            if (!result.Value)
            {
                selectedtype.MakeClean();
                return true; // ignore changes
            }

            // Ask the data service to save for us
            await dataservice.UpdateClientType(selectedtype);
            selectedtype.MakeClean();
            return true;
    }
}
```

Two columns, left hand holds a list of entities that when one is selected, the details column on the right updates to allow view/edit. If an entity is edited by the user in the right panel I mark its view model "dirty".

When the user tries to select a different entity in the left column, I'd like to be able to (in the ViewModel) ask the user if they want to navigate away and lose their changes, or if they'd like to save them.

This I can present (through a navigation service), but I'm at a loss as to how to actually make the "cancel" work in the view model that is making me rethink my whole approach.

If I was binding the `SelectedItem` in both directions then I think I could just not update the underlying field before the `RaisePropertyChanged` is fired - but as I would need to call into async code to persist my entity (HttpClient) I can't do that from within a property setter.

So I've gone with the above that I can't really get working without what feels like horrible hacks.

Is there a better general solution to this that I'm just not seeing? Or even better an example out there?

**EDIT**

I've realised that its not clear what I'm trying to accomplish here. The issue is not how to *revert* changes made, as @Alan has rightly pointed out there are some standard ways to deal with that.

I'm asking the user the following on an attempt to change the selected type in the left pane:

*Do you want to save this type?*

[Yes] - save and allow navigation

[No] - revert changes and allow navigation

[Cancel] - keep changes and cancel navigation

Its [Cancel] that I have no idea how to handle properly.

Comment: Have you looked at the IEditableObject interface? Can you not just clone the object and revert back to the original instance if you cancel? Or on a simpler object keep a copy of each field maybe.

Comment: I hadn't seen IEditableObject no - that's useful thankyou. However that isn't actually my issue - I'm asking the user if they want to CANCEL attempting to navigate away from the edited details. In otherwords, abort the navigation in the first place. Any ideas on the right pattern to attack that with?

Comment: Yes, it was not clear. Thanks for the update and clarification. I was thinking when I originally read it that you should have led with the problem in the first section. I posted a new answer that I think should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer is in the Prism book by implementing IConfirmNavigationRequest?

**Confirming or Cancelling Navigation**

You will often find that you will need to interact with the user during a navigation operation, so that the user can confirm or cancel it. In many applications, for example, the user may try to navigate while in the middle of entering or editing data. In these situations, you may want to ask the user whether he or she wants to save or discard the data that has been entered before continuing to navigate away from the page, or whether the user wants to cancel the navigation operation altogether. Prism supports these scenarios via the IConfirmNavigationRequest interface.

From the Prism book
[8: Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec12)